# C++: Store contents of text file into 2D array as strings (trouble with null terminator?)

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, c-strings

I'm working a bit more with arrays and reading from files to try and get a deeper understanding of them, so I apologize if I ask a lot of questions in regards to that.

I currently have a program that is supposed to read characters from a file and then store those characters as strings into a 2D array. As an example, this file contains a header number and a list of names:

```
5
Billy
Joe
Sally
Sarah
Jeff
```

So the 2D array in this case will have 5 rows and x number of columns (one row per names). The program reads the file one char at a time. I think what I'm having problem with is actually inserting the null terminator at the end of each row to indicate that it's the end of that string, but overall, I'm not sure what's going wrong. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_NAME_LENGTH = 50;

void printNames(char [][MAX_NAME_LENGTH + 1], int);

int main(void)
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    string filename;
    int headernum, i = 0, j;
    const int MAX_NAMES = 10;
    char ch;
    char names[1][MAX_NAME_LENGTH + 1];

    cout << "Please enter the name of your input file: ";
    cin >> filename;

    inputFile.open(filename.c_str());

    if (inputFile.fail())
    {
        cout << "Input file could not be opened. Try again." << endl;
    }

    inputFile >> headernum;

    if (headernum > MAX_NAMES)
    {
        cout << "Maximum number of names cannot exceed " << MAX_NAMES << ". Please try again." << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    inputFile.get(ch);

    while (!inputFile.eof())
    {
        for (i = 0; i < headernum; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < MAX_NAME_LENGTH; j++)
            {
                if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\n')
                {
                    names[i][j] = '\0';
                }

                else
                {
                    names[i][j] = ch;
                }
            }
        }

        inputFile.get(ch);
    }

    cout << names[0] << endl;
    //printNames(names, headernum);

    return 0;
}

void printNames(char fnames[][MAX_NAME_LENGTH + 1], int fheadernum)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < fheadernum; i++)
    {
        cout << fnames[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

It compiles, and here is the output: http://puu.sh/7pyXV.png

So obviously something is very wrong here! I'm incline to say the specific problem lies with  my if (ch = ' ' etc) statement, but it could be much more than that, I'm sure. I'm just having trouble figuring out where the problem lies. As always, help and/or guidance is very much appreciated!

Comment: Look at the order you are doing things in.  You are reading a character, and then doing your `i` and `j` loops . Then once those loops have finished (assigning every cell in your array with the same value) then you read another character.  I think what you want to do instead is read a character inside the `j` loop.

Comment: Also, `names` only has 1 row, but your `i` loop goes over `headernum` rows. This is a buffer overflow. I think you meant to use `MAX_NAMES` instead of `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you have some feedback on your initial code. Here is a much simpler way of doing this (and a bit more c++ like):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ifstream inputFile;
  string filename;

  cout << "Please enter the name of your input file: ";
  cin >> filename;

  inputFile.open(filename.c_str());

  if (inputFile.fail())
  {
      cout << "Input file could not be opened. Try again." << endl;
      return 1;
  }

  int headerNum = 0;
  inputFile >> headerNum;
  if(inputFile.eof()) {
      cout << "Error reading input file contents." << endl;
      return 1;
  }

  string *names = new string[headerNum];
  for(int i = 0; i < headerNum; i++)
    inputFile >> names[i];

  for(int i = 0; i < headerNum; i++)
    cout << names[i] << endl;

}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works much simpler than mine (and looks better, too!) If you don't mind, could you explain a little bit about what's going on with `string *names = new string[headerNum]`? As in, why use that instead of declaring `string[MAX_NAMES]`?

Comment: Sure, this is dynamically allocating an array of 'string' of size headerNum. Note that string *names is a string pointer. So basically what is happening is that a big chunk of memory is allocated to hold 'headerNum' strings and then the address of this chunk of memory is assigned to 'names'. By using names[i] the compiler knows how to access element i in this chunk of memory because it knows the size of string (i.e. i * sizeof(string))

Comment: If you are happy with this answer then please don't forget to mark it as correct :)

Comment: Just a bit more on the 'string *names = new string[headerNum]' line. The actual reason that I do it this way is that using 'new' you can create an array of any size where the size can be determined at runtime. Conversly, using 'char names[1][MAX_NAME_LENGTH + 1]' the size must be known at compile time.